# checkManifest ERROR android

Tags: android, android-emulator

Using the code
GCMRegistrar.checkManifest (this);
My application (android) I generates the following error:
  No receiver for package com.saluteonline

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.saluteonline"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0" >

<!-- GCM requires Android SDK version 2.2 (API level 8) or above. -->
<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="8"
    android:targetSdkVersion="16" />

<!-- GCM connects to Internet Services. -->
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />

<!-- GCM requires a Google account. -->
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />

<!-- Keeps the processor from sleeping when a message is received. -->
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />

<!-- Creates a custom permission so only this app can receive its messages. -->
<permission
    android:name="com.androidhive.pushnotifications.permission.C2D_MESSAGE"
    android:protectionLevel="signature" />

<uses-permission android:name="com.androidhive.pushnotifications.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" />

<!-- This app has permission to register and receive data message. -->
<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE" />

<!-- Network State Permissions to detect Internet status -->
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />

<!-- Permission to vibrate -->
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />


<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity android:name=".MainActivity_test"></activity>
    <activity android:name=".RegistrationActivity"></activity>
    <activity android:name=".retriveMessage"></activity>
    <activity android:name=".CustomizedListView"></activity>
    <activity android:name=".viewMessage"></activity>


   <receiver
        android:name="com.google.android.gcm.GCMBroadcastReceiver"
        android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND" >
        <intent-filter>

            <!-- Receives the actual messages. -->
            <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />
            <!-- Receives the registration id. -->
            <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.REGISTRATION" />

            <category android:name="com.androidhive.pushnotifications" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>

    <service android:name=".GCMIntentService" />
</application>

</manifest>
```

I see the similar error in both emulator and phone

Comment: Thoguh I am not sure but try and Change your package name to `com.saluteonline.somthing` . Check the package creating conventions: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_package#Package_naming_conventions Eg: ` If an organization in Canada called MySoft creates a package to deal with fractions, naming the package ca.mysoft.fractions distinguishes the fractions package from another similar package created by another company.`

Comment: what error u r getting

Answer (score 0):

The places you are using com.androidhive.pushnotifications you should use your own app package name com.salutonline .for more information you should check demo example of android gcm at developers android.The sample manifest has comments that explain everything very well.

Check this manifest from Demo Activity Android Developer Docs:

```
<!-- GCM requires Android SDK version 2.2 (API level 8) or above. -->
<!-- The targetSdkVersion is optional, but it's always a good practice
     to target higher versions. -->
<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="8" android:targetSdkVersion="16"/>

<!-- GCM connects to Google Services. -->
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />

<!-- GCM requires a Google account. -->
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />

<!-- Keeps the processor from sleeping when a message is received. -->
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />

<!--
 Creates a custom permission so only this app can receive its messages.

 NOTE: the permission *must* be called PACKAGE.permission.C2D_MESSAGE,
       where PACKAGE is the application's package name.
-->
<permission
    android:name="com.google.android.gcm.demo.app.permission.C2D_MESSAGE"
    android:protectionLevel="signature" />
<uses-permission
    android:name="com.google.android.gcm.demo.app.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" />

<!-- This app has permission to register and receive data message. -->
<uses-permission
    android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE" />

<!-- Main activity. -->
<application
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name" >
    <activity
        android:name=".DemoActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

    <!--
      BroadcastReceiver that will receive intents from GCM
      services and handle them to the custom IntentService.

      The com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND permission is necessary
      so only GCM services can send data messages for the app.
    -->
    <receiver
        android:name="com.google.android.gcm.GCMBroadcastReceiver"
        android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND" >
        <intent-filter>
            <!-- Receives the actual messages. -->
            <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />
            <!-- Receives the registration id. -->
            <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.REGISTRATION" />
            <category android:name="com.google.android.gcm.demo.app" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>

    <!--
      Application-specific subclass of GCMBaseIntentService that will
      handle received messages.

      By default, it must be named .GCMIntentService, unless the
      application uses a custom BroadcastReceiver that redefines its name.
    -->
    <service android:name=".GCMIntentService" />
</application>
```